# Change Mac OS X Sidebar Icons

Tags: macos, finder, icon, sidebar

I have been unsuccessfully trying to change the Mac sidebar icons without the use of 3rd party software.

As pointed out here, [Change Mac OS X Finder sidebar icons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76897/change-mac-os-x-finder-sidebar-icons), it would seem that editing the file /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist should be the answer.

The original file converted to xml looks like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
    <string>SidebarDesktopFolder.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>Sidebar Desktop Folder Icon</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>sbDt</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>None</string>
    <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSPersistentStoreTypeKey</key>
    <string>Binary</string>
</dict>
```

To test this, i thought if i would change SidebarDesktopFolder.icns to SidebarDocumentsFolder.icns and Sidebar Desktop Folder Icon to Sidebar Documents Folder Icon and the string sbDt to sbDc i would reroute the reference for the sidebar icon.

However, this did not work, nothing seems any different.

Does anyone know where the reference to the icon file is that needs to be changed?

Comment: did you read this http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23327/46541

Comment: I did, and it is what got me as far as i did, but changing the values as indicated does not seem to work